# How to make the close button of Fancybox invisible?

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I do not want the user to be able to close the fancybox by clicking the default close button at the upper right corner :

[image]

```
$("a#ExporterSujetReponse", context).fancybox({
    'onStart': function () {

            loadDeverouillerSujetAvecReponse (this) ;

    },
    'overlayOpacity':0.4,
    'overlayColor':'#000000',
    'titleShow':false,
    'hideOnOverlayClick':false,
    'centerOnScroll':true,
    'onComplete' : function(){
            $.fancybox.resize();
            $('#fancybox-content').removeAttr('style').css({ 'height' : $(window).height()-100, 'margin' : '0 auto', 'width' : $(window).width()-150 });
    }
});
```

So how to make the default close button invisible ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use  `'showCloseButton':false`

```
$("a#ExporterSujetReponse", context).fancybox({
  ...
  'showCloseButton':false, // add this line to hide close button
  ....
});
```